# How to call a function without passing a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++

Just leaning C++, here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int absouteValue(int number);

int main()
{
    cout << absouteValue(-6);
    return 0;
}

int absouteValue(int number)
{
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> number;

    if (number < 0) 
    {
        number = number * -1;
    }
    else
    {
        number = number;
    }

    return number;
}
```

I want the absoluteValue function to return the absolute value of a number that is inputted from the user. It is doing this somewhat but I am bumping in to the following problem:

In my main function, I don't want to have to input a value when I call the `absoluteValue`. I would like the user to do that. But I have to pass through a value into the parameter number. Even if I pass -6, and I input -31, the answer that the program returns is 31, which is correct. Is there a way to just call the function from main without having to pass through my own number?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change the method signature and method definition "int absouteValue(int number)" to int absouteValue(). So you dont have to pass "-6" as argument.

Comment: Err... What do you mean?

Comment: Why are you passing any value to begin with???

Comment: What a wonderful program, and I can not understand

Comment: Your effort-saving thoughts are actually detrimental. First, nobody expects a function called `absoluteValue` to take input and give output. You could call it `outputPromptAndGetInputAndCalculateAbsoluteValue`. Now, do you see a problem with this name? I do, but the name is not the core cause. The function is doing too much. You should restrict it to just calculating the absolute value of a given number. What if you later want the number to come from a file? Or be random? What if you want to test your function (hint: `INT_MIN`)? Do you seriously want to input numbers every time you run a test?

Comment: @chris - I think I understand what you're getting at -- make functions very simple and make them do very specific things. And I agree with that. I guess my question is how do i make the function AbsoluteValue() simple enough where I can make the user input a number and have main() call AbsoluteValue() and compute the absolute value of that number?

Answer (score 3):

Using Standard input `(cin)` you can have your user enter a number and pass it on your method.

```
int main()
{
 cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
cin >> number;
cout << absouteValue(number);
return 0;
}

int absouteValue(int number)
{
    if (number < 0) 
    {
        number = number * -1;
    }
    else
    {
        number = number;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: @zenith ,code changed.Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the int number argument from your method. And create the variable in the method.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int absouteValue(int number);

int main()

{
    cout << absouteValue();

    return 0;
}

int absouteValue()

{

    int number;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> number;


    if (number < 0) 
    {
        number = number * -1;

    }

    else
    {
        number = number;
    }


    return number;
}
```

Comment: Why should a function called `absoluteValue` do input and output? Move all that stuff out and keep the parameter.

Comment: With so much vertical space, it's hard to spot the differences.  I know where they are because I know _what_ they are, but it might not be obvious to a novice.

Answer (score -1):

You can move the cin to the main, and pass that to the function.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int absouteValue(int number); 
int main() 
{ 
    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number" << endl; 
    cin >> number; 
    cout << absouteValue(number);
    return 0; 
} 

int absouteValue(int number) 
{ 
    if (number < 0) { 
        number = number * -1; 
    } else { 
        number = number; 
    } 
    return number; 
}
```

The difference is that the user inputs the number inside the main function into the variable *number*, then we pass the variable into the function.

If there's anything else that needs clarification, please comment.

Comment: "and pass that". What? `cin`? `main`? The variable? Please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing this on my mobile phone, so the code wasn't good the first time :(